# Magento2 controller not found, auto-loading namespace using composer

Tags: php, composer-php, magento2

I get 404 not found error while running
`https://example.com/uicustomer/index/test`
Please help!!

vendor\magento2-vendor-ui_customer\Controller\Index\Test.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\UiCustomer\Controller\Index;
class Test extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
protected $_pageFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
{
    $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    return parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    echo "Hello World";
    exit;
}
}
```

vendor\magento2-vendor-ui_customer\etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Vendor_UiCustomer" setup_version="1.1.3">
</module>
</config>
```

vendor\magento2-vendor-ui_customer\etc\frontend\routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="standard">
    <route frontName="uicustomer" id="uicustomer">
        <module name="Vendor_UiCustomer"/>
    </route>
</router>
</config>
```

vendor\magento2-vendor-ui_customer\composer.json

```
{
  "name": "vendor/magento2-vendor-ui_customer",
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
  "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Vendor\\UiCustomer\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

vendor\magento2-vendor-ui_customer\registration.php

```
<?php
use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;
ComponentRegistrar::register(
ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Vendor_UiCustomer',
__DIR__
);
```

Comment: I just looked into composer/autoload_psr4.php it doesn't generate the namespace in this file

Answer (score 0):

So I read through the whole Magento 2.3 document and found out that the problem was with the "UI" text in the namespace. According to the document, it is not allowed. Probably a bug. So I had to change UICustomer to ExtCustomer and it solved the problem

```
{
"name": "vendor/magento2-vendor-ui_customer",
"autoload": {
"files": [
"registration.php"
],
"psr-4": {
  "Vendor\\UiCustomer\\": ""
}
}
}
```